# Check If Everything In Head Is Less Than Tail

Tags: prolog

Given a list containing sublists [[1].[2],[3]] how would I check to see if HEAD of the first sublist in the list is less than the rest of the HEADS of the other sublists?

Comment: Think about what you might you be able to do with `map head`.

Comment: @ChetterHummin I haven't tried much. I'm not really sure how to go about this.

Comment: Pretty much all of the functions you need are listed on this page: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html Think about how you can mix and match them.

Answer (score 2):

[Comparison of *Standard Order of Terms*](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%283,%274.7.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/compare.html%27%29%29) in ISO-Prolog can be applied - recursively - to arbitrary complex structures.

Then your problem could be solved with something like

```
first_head_is_less([H|R]) :- maplist(@<(H), R).
```

test:

```
?- first_head_is_less([[1],[2],[3]]).
true.

?- first_head_is_less([[10],[2],[3]]).
false.
```

*edit* the code above must be refined, because it fail (for instance) on this:

```
?- first_head_is_less([[1,2],[1,3],[3]]).
true.
```

which is incorrect. Here a stricter test:

```
first_head_is_less([H|R]) :-
    maplist(head_is_less(H), R).
head_is_less([F|_], [E|_]) :- F @< E.
```